# how to generalize my SQL requests

Tags: php, sql

I haven't spent too much time on optimizing my code or improving its modularity as i have been learning PHP but i think it is time to do so. The first thing I want to improve is my SQL calls. I make a ton of different SQL queries and they all follow a couple of different patterns. I usually just copy one, paste it somewhere and change the things I need to. Obviously thats the red flag that I need to modularize them.

My question is that I don't understand how i can do it, because each table I access has different amounts of variables, and sometimes i want one or two, and others i want the whole table. Also, sometimes I want to pick by id, sometimes by name etc. I am looking for just a point in the right direction here, just having some trouble figuring out how I should do this. Here are some examples of my queries below:

```
function pricesByAlcohol($alcID) {
    $query = 'SELECT store_id, price FROM price WHERE alc_id = '.$alcID;
    //echo $query."<br>";
    $i= 0; //index
    $result = array();

    if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($query)){ 
        /* execute statement */
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($store_id, $price);
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $result[$i] = array('store' => $store_id, 
                                    'price' => $price);
                $i++;
                //echo $id." ".$img."/".$text."<br>";
            }
        } else
            //echo "error";

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        //echo "Prepare in fetchActiveAds failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    return $result;
}

function store($storeID) {
    $query = 'SELECT name, address, gps FROM store WHERE id = '.$storeID;
    //echo $query."<br>";

    if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($query)){ 
        /* execute statement */
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($name, $address, $gps);
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $result = array('name' => $name, 
                                'address' => $address,
                                'gps' => $gps);
                //echo $id." ".$img."/".$text."<br>";
            }
        } else
            //echo "error";

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        //echo "Prepare in fetchActiveAds failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    return $result;
}

function getAlcoholIDByNameSize($name, $size) {
    $query = 'SELECT id FROM alcohol WHERE size_id = '.$size.' AND name = "'.$name.'"';
    //echo $query."<br>";

    if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($query)){ 
        /* execute statement */
        if($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $result = $id;
                //echo $id." ".$img."/".$text."<br>";
            }
        } else
            //echo "error";

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        //echo "Prepare in fetchActiveAds failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: One thing that will help you going forward is learning to use parametrized queries, preferably using PDO as your database layer.  What you're doing now, with building SQL statements from variables, is prone to SQL injection and quoting errors.  Take a look at http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of how to write parametrized queries in PHP.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 2):

You're using SQL the way it's supposed to be used.

Although it might not be the thing you're after, you could try some ORM mechanism to hide the SQL queries and results retrieval behind classic OOP. That will clean up your code big time. For PHP you can find some pointers on the below thread:

[Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)